# Ansible 2.4 hostfile warning

Tags: ansible

In Ansible 2.4, I'm getting this deprecation warning:

```
[DEPRECATION WARNING]: [defaults]hostfile option, The key is misleading as it can also be a list of hosts, a directory or a list of
paths . This feature will be removed in version 2.8. Deprecation warnings can be disabled by setting deprecation_warnings=False in
ansible.cfg.
```

For the life of me, I cannot figure out what this means.  Anybody know?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In my ansible.cfg file, I had a line like

```
hostfile = ./inventory
```

That needs to be changed to

```
inventory = ./inventory
```

Comment: As you figured out `hostfile` is deprecated in favor of `inventory`: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/porting_guide_2.4.html#specifying-inventory-sources

Comment: Wasn't that a round-about way of putting it though?